# Evenly spaced numbers between two sets (Vectorize LINSPACE) - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, vectorization

How can I define a matrix `M` according to `M=[a:(b-a)/5:b]` (from `a` to `b` in 5 steps), when `a` and `b` are vectors or sets; more specifically, each row `i` in `M` should have a first value equal to `a(i)` and last value `b(i)` and, in between, 5 equal steps.

For example, if I have

```
a = [0;     b = [10;
     0];         20];
```

I'd like to produce a matrix `M` of the form

```
[0 2 4  6  8 10;...
 0 4 8 12 16 20]
```

I know how to do this using loops, but I'm looking for a solution without. How can I do that?

Comment: so you want to vectorize the notion of `linspace`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One [`vectorized`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html) approach with [`bsxfun`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
steps = 5                               %// number of steps
M = bsxfun(@plus,((b(:)-a(:))./(steps-1))*[0:steps-1],a(:))
```

Sample run -

```
a =
     2
     3
b =
    18
    23
M =
     2     6    10    14    18
     3     8    13    18    23
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way using `arrayfun` (slower than @Divakar's `bsxfun` solution) but just for the sake of it:

```
clear
clc

a=[0;0];
b=[10;20];

%// Customize the stepsize
Step = 5;

M = cell2mat(arrayfun(@(a,b) (a:(b-a)/Step:b), a,b,'uni',false))

M =

     0     2     4     6     8    10
     0     4     8    12    16    20
```