# how to use bsxfun with linspace [1 5] -> [1 2 3 5 6 7]

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

In matlab I'm attempting to get from a vector

```
start=[1 5 10]
```

to a solution looking like this, adding [1:3] to every value, expanding the vector:

```
sol=[1 2 3 5 6 7 10 11 12]
```

I tried

```
fun=@(a,b) a-b:a;
test=3
bsxfun(fun,start,test)
```

but it only works for the first value (`start(1)`). How can I turn the variable start into something like the solution vector?

[Related answer I couldn't make work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29034188/evenly-spaced-numbers-between-two-sets-vectorize-linspace-matlab)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the first and second inputs to the function provided to [`bsxfun` aren't necessarily scalars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41536953/bsxfun-doesnt-work-as-i-expect-on-a-constant-function/41537082#41537082).

In your example, the *array* `[1, 5, 10]` is being passed as the first input to your anonymous function and `colon` ignores all but the first element if the first input is an array

```
colon([1 5 10], 3)
%   1   2   3
```

To accomplish what you're trying to do, you can just add `0:2` to each element of `start` using `@plus` and reshape the result to be a row vector.

```
reshape(bsxfun(@plus, start, (0:2).'), 1, [])
```

What this actually does is adds `[0, 1, 2]` to each element of `start`

```
bsxfun(@plus, start, (0:2).')
% 1     5    10
% 2     6    11
% 3     7    12
```

And then we reshape this into a row vector. Since MATLAB uses column-major ordering, the reshaped data will go down the columns and yield the expected result.

Or if you're on R2016b or newer

```
reshape(start + (0:2).', 1, [])
```

Comment: can you elaborate on the solution code a bit? I don't know why you use a dot in front of the transformation hyphen in reshape(start + (0:2).', 1, []) and looking at the result of bsxfun(@plus, start, (0:2)') I can't really follow the reshaping.

Comment: @user2305193 `'` is a complex conjugate transpose which is generally not what one wants. What you want is a regular matrix transpose, which is given by `.'` So for a real valued matrix there's no difference (besides `.'`  being slightly faster), but it prevents you from ruining your result when you use your code for complex valued matrices. ( `'` is an apostrophe btb, `-` is a hyphen)

Comment: obviously this answer can easily be expanded to expand vectors in either direction using bsxfun(@plus, start, (X:Y).') e.g. X=-2 and Y=2.